# Worried about being refused entry into Schengen

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, spain, netherlands

Hi I just got a Schengen visa and I am pleased about that. But at the same time, I'm worried about being refused entry. So the issue is that I applied from the NL embassy (VFS center) for NL and Spain. I intend to stay on the 10th and 11th Jan in NL and on the 12th I have a flight from NL to Spain; I'll stay in Spain from 12th Jan to 17th Jan.

As per the rules, I was supposed to apply from the Spain embassy instead of the NL embassy. When I reached VFS, they first refused, saying *we can't proceed with your application as you were supposed to apply from Spain instead of NL.* At the same time they asked me to do a small update in my NL hotel booking so that, instead of 12th Jan being the checkout, 14th Jan was, to make it look like a valid case. I also had to submit my application without an itinerary.

Now, the cover letter clearly mentions that I'll leave NL on the 12th of Jan but my "FAKE UPDATED" hotel booking says I have a booking until the 14th of Jan. Other documents like an invitation from the NL person and ES person, say that I'll stay until 12th in NL and 12-17 Jan in ES.

I have finally got the visa but I'm a bit worried that I'll get entry denied because of this thing. Since all the submitted documents said that I would leave NL on the 12th while my hotel booking is supposedly until 14th Jan in NL. Should I even be worried about this? Can they even deny the entry just because I will stay in NL for just one and a half days and stay most of the days in Spain?

Comment: What are the reasons for the visits to NL and ES, respectively? The rules is NOT that you should apply for a visa from the country where you stay the longest, but based on the main purpose of the visit, and duration is a tie-breaker. So for instance if you go to NL for business or a conference and ES for tourism, then NL is the main reason. If you go to both for tourism then duration is what counts.

Comment: It's business for both countries. I applied for a business visa. I work as a freelancer for a Dutch company and they have offices in Spain also. So there's a year end meeting that I need to attend in both of the countries. @jcaron

Comment: A bit difficult to make a point that NL is the main destination, though you could say you are visiting HQ, main reason, and while you're there, ES offices. But I wonder, why did you apply from NL? I'm quite surprised that VFS asked you to adjust your booking. I really don't expect much difficulty as you actually have a valid reason for travel to both, and picking NL over ES does not really look like "visa shopping" to me, but if they want to be picky they can take quite a bit of your time.

Comment: @jcaron but they won't deny the entry, right? If I have valid stays, a copy of the contract with the NL company, tickets to Spain, invitations from both countries, and flight ticket back from ES to home country

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me. The Schengen Border Code says you need to be able to justify your stay etc, but I don’t think it says anything about justifying why you applied from one country rather than another. Will your point of entry be AMS? With a NL visa and justification for the stay in NL they should be happy.

Comment: @jcaron yep VISA is issued by NL

Answer (score 3):

Warning: I'm not an immigration officer, so whatever I say has *no* legal validity, and there are several instances below where I'm just guessing, and I got tired with putting a disclaimer at every point, so I just put this at the top!

The immigration officers at the border can *always* deny anyone entry.

Normally they only deny entry to people carrying a visa if they suspect fraud was involved in obtaining the visa. If they (like me, based on your post) suspect fraud they will at least ask you extra questions, so don't make plans for shortly after arrival.

Some things you don't mention (and that is suspect) is when you received the invitations, when you booked the flights, when you booked the hotels (not the fraudulent extension of the NL booking, and based on what you say, it's quite clear the extension is fraudulent, as it stands it can probably just cause more questions), and when you applied for the visa, and why you applied to the Dutch embassy, when you seem to know that you should have applied to the Spanish embassy.

Comment: can they refuse the entry just on the fact that I am not staying in NL more than Spain? Even though I have everything like looking, flight to Spain and then back to my home country and hotel booking?

Also, when I go for immigration at do they have a copy of all docs that I submitted at VFS?

Comment: They can refuse you entry because they feel like it, they seldom do that, and they also know that plans can change, so if they don't get to suspect fraud in any other way, they probably (repeat the warning) won't refuse entry *just* because you're staying longer in another country from the one that issued the visa. I don't know if they always get a copy of all the docs you submitted, but don't be surprised if they have them.

Comment: @Shivam The visa application information is contained in the VIS database, which immigration can see. Remember you are the one who signed the application confirming that the Netherlands is the country where you will spend the longest period.

Comment: @Shivam they don't need any reason to reject you. They can reject you because they didn't like the movie they saw last night and are in a bad mood as a result. They probably won't, as they tend to be good professionals, but they can. But you fudging your reasons for stay and fraudulently changing your hotel booking to make it appear you're staying in the Netherlands when not intending to will definitely raise eyebrows and may lead to being rejected.